# No more free storage space

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, internal-sd

My Galaxy S2 plus (4.2.2 JB) keeps saying I only have 416 Mb of free space on my internal space despite moving all apps to external storage and deleting junk files. Any solutions for this persistent problem?

Comment: I think it is an application that is notifying about less memory. R u using cleaning apps?

Comment: Happy for you. Please add your answer so that others with same problem get benefited.

Answer (score 1):

You can root your mobile and can use some partition tool or go through this link http://www.android.gs/increase-galaxy-ace-internal-memory/.

Comment: Rooting isn't a solution.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll check them out; but I already found my own solution. Cheers!

Comment: @MANI By itself, rooting isn't a solution, but it is only one of the steps that vikki listed in the overall solution here. And the OP didn't specify they only wanted non-root solutions.

Comment: Solution: use foldermount to move all apps with big data storage to your ext sd card. Simple and easy. All you need is a rooted phone and internet acces to download the app from the playstore. The rest is easy...